# Does groundhog seasonal shedding cause itching

Tags: animals, animal-behaviour

We live in a heavily wooded area with a heavily wooded bluff off our back yard. Wildlife is abundant here, including groundhogs. Until we installed cams to watch wildlife I’d never witnessed the shedding process of groundhogs (or any wildlife).

I’m wondering if the shedding process causes itching, as I’ve seen one scratch on occasion?

Comment: I don't know about groundhogs, but cats, dogs, squirrels, moose, all scratch a lot.  I think any furred, feathered, or haired animal scratches.  Possibly they (and we) are all shedding to some extent all the time.  I wonder if snakes do an equivalent of scratching by rubbing themselves against a frictional surface.

Comment: Thanks for the info. This is the first year I’ve put up cams specifically to watch the wildlife, so I’m seeing way more and learning far more than I anticipated. The behaviors I’ve seen have been amazing and surprising, but some of them itching is curious though unsure if worrisome at this point. One of the juveniles appears to have a botfly warble.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: Yes.

Longer answer: Yes, but that's not the only likely cause of itching in animals. There are parasites like lice, chiggers, fleas, mosquitoes, mites  (mange) etc. that can all cause itching too. In addition, fungal skin infections tend to be itchy. In general you should avoid the areas where you see itching animals as they may be shedding parasites like mites and fleas.

There are also spontaneous itches (as you will likely have experienced yourself - a random itch on your arm for instance).

Comment: Another cause of itching: reading lists of things that cause itching.

Comment: Off topic - For people who love being outdoors enjoying nature and wilderness, and learning about the required skills and equipment. It's built and run by you as part of the Stack Exchange network of Q&A sites.

Comment: @GBG I fail to see how questions about animal behaviour observed in the wild are off-topic for an outdoors forum. Sure, the question might be better suited to a different SE, but I think it is perfectly on-topic here especially as animal behaviour is one topic specifically mentioned in the [on-topic](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) list

Comment: @bob1 I don't see animal health or behavior in this list but I do see Outdoor animals/pests in the house or yard listed at contentious.
 https://outdoors.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/list-of-everything-that-has-been-declared-on-or-off-topic-on-the-outdoors-se

Comment: @GBG second to last bullet point in my link: `bird & animal watching and behaviour`

Comment: @bob1 - no worriesl- I did not mean to offend.  My account at the great outdoors site is scheduled for deletion.  This site lack moderation and focus.

Comment: @GBG no offense taken. I agree that moderation here could be stronger, but to reach mod status on SE, you need to accumulate "reputation", and as this is one of the smaller SE's it takes a while for more than a few people to get enough reputation.

Comment: @user20551 I don’t see anything in my post as contentious at all. I don’t see any wildlife as “Pests” and never will, and we welcome them all to our property and garden and maintain our property for wildlife. I apologize if I posted in the wrong forum, but it wasn’t intentional. This was my very first post on this site so am still learning.

Comment: @csk I’m not sure if your comment was meant to be humorous, but I am concerned for wildlife that may be in distress. the only info I find online is of the “Get rid of” kind. This particular site I thought I could find more information here. I love groundhogs and find watching them a true learning experience. They are one of the most misunderstood and persecuted animals, and few seem to care about them. But I care, which is why I’m asking.

I’m just trying to learn more about their behavior and have likely posted in the wrong area. I certainly didn’t mean to be disruptive to the topic here.

Comment: @SummerShadow Don't worry - you are perfectly on-topic here and not disrupting. User20551 has deleted their account (used to be called GBG) and was a new-comer to this site too. They didn't read the community guidelines or what was on/off-topic (even when specifically linked) before posting their comments.

Comment: @SummerShadow Your question is definitely on topic here.  We have had some discussions in the past about whether "backyard" questions are on topic.  I don't think that discussion is fully resolved -- for example a question about ants at a backyard picnic would probably be declared off topic -- but a moose interruping a backyard picnic would be on topic.  Groundhogs and other wildlife are on topic!

Comment: @SummerShadow Yes, my comment was meant to be humorous, but I didn't mean to mock you or your concern for wildlife. You asked a good and interesting question, and I found bob1's answer quite informative. I just thought that was funny that I felt itchy after reading about all those things that can cause itching.